# filtering knockout.js viewModel

Tags: javascript, c#, mvvm, knockout.js

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#previewApplicantModal" data-bind="attr: { 'data-applicationKey': application.applicationKey }">
 Preview Application
</a>
```

By giving the data-bind="attr: {data-applicationKey : application.applicationKey}, the link above gets a new data-binding :

```
data-applicationkey="abc9hansg"
```

And this applicationKey is stored in a viewModel called application which was called this way:

```
self.applications = ko.observableArray(@Html.Json(Model.ApplicationCompatibilities.Select(o => o.JsonForm)) || []);
```

What I wanted to do is, I want to filter the original array (applications) and return the only application that has the same applicationKey as the one bound with the link.

In other words, I want to retrieve the applicationKey from

```
data-applicationkey="abc9hansg"
```

and filter out the application that has this "applicationKey".

What I have so far is:

```
                self.previewApplicationKey = ko.observable(null);

                self.previewApplication = ko.computed(function () {
                    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.applications(), function (i) {
                        return i.application.applicationKey === self.previewApplicationKey();
                    });
                });
```

So I am having trouble with handling the "self.previewApplicationKey" and putting the data bound "applicationKey" to this viewModel.

Please Help!

EDIT:

What I want to do is, I want to add a link that loads a modal. And inside that modal I want to display the specific "application" that has a specific "applicationKey"

For example, the link to the modal will look like this:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#previewApplicantModal" data-bind="attr: { **data-applicationKey': application.applicationKey** }">
     Preview Application
</a>
```

So If I inspect the element of the link, it has a new data-binding:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#previewApplicantModal" data-bind="attr: { 'data-applicationKey': application.applicationKey }" data-applicationkey="abc976cfx">
    Preview Application
</a>
```

Finally I want to loop through the "application" object and return only "one" element of the object that has "abc976cfx" as its applicationKey.

Is there an easy way of doing this? I attached a screenshot for better explanation.

[image]

Comment: What trouble are you having? Do you get an error?

Comment: @JasonSpake I am not getting an error, but I want to retrieve the data-applicationKey binding and compare it with the i.application.applicationKey. To do this, I assume that I have to add the data-applicationKey of the link to the previewApplicationKey model. How do I do that?

Comment: Are you saying that an "ApplciationKey" property already exists on the "application" model? If so what is preventing you from using that directly?

Comment: Yes. The "ApplciationKey" already exists on the "application" model. Could you please check my Edit? So what I want to do is, I want to return the only one element of the "application" model which "applicationKey" matches the data-bind (data-applicationKey) of the link that loads the model.